# jQuery cycle - can the transition cycle through all slides

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle, jquery-cycle

I need to tweak a jQuery carousel I have made using the excellent cycle plugin
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Basiaclly, as you can see from this demo (
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager11.html), if you click '3' on the pager from '1' or vice-versa, that slide will slide in without seeing slide 2

Is there a quick way to tweak the settings so the scrollHorz will cycle from 3 to 2 to 1 rather then just 3 to 1.

It would be good if its possible as it kind of retains the order.

Ta in advance as always,
A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem recently and couldn't find a way to get jQuery.Cycle to do what you're describing. I ended up using jQuery.jCarousel instead.

Here's an example: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_controls.html

Make sure to set the scroll and visible options to 1 so that only one element is shown at a time.